# Aggregate function like MAX for most common cell in column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Group by the highest Number in a column worked great with `MAX()`, but what if I would like to get the cell that is at most common.

As example:

```
ID
100
250
250
300
200
250
```

So I would like to group by ID and instead of get the lowest (MIN) or highest (MAX) number, I would like to get the most common one (that would be `250`, because there 3x).

Is there an easy way in SQL Server 2012 or am I forced to add a second `SELECT` where I `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` and add that somehow to my first `SELECT` statement?

Comment: There may be a way to do this with `select top 1 with ties`, but I don't entirely understand your query.  I'd rather see your code than read a description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dense_rank` to return all the id's with the highest counts. This would handle cases when there are ties for the highest counts as well.

```
select id from
(select id, dense_rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rnk from tablename group by id) t
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do what you want uses `top` and `order by`:

```
SELECT top 1 id
FROM t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This is a statistic called the `mode`.  Getting the mode and max is a bit challenging in SQL Server.  I would approach it as:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT t.id, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM t
      GROUP BY id
     )
SELECT MAX(id) AS themax, MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN id END) AS MODE
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Please add `with ties` or add warning.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Everything in the question is singular.  I will note:  Use `with ties` if you want multiple rows that are most common in the event that there are multiple modes.

Comment: Nice one avoiding a sub query.